# On double click of li element jQuery scroll goes to top of the screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to finish my portfolio but when I click on a list element in my navbar it takes me to where I want to go, but when I click on the same element again it takes me back to the top. I think it's because jQuery is scrolling to the href and in the list element I have an anchor with href. How can I stop this?

The jQuery -

```
  $('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('[name="' + $.attr(this, 'href').substr(1) + '"]').offset().top
    }, 500); 
  });
```

[JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/c294z61y/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is that you haven't accounted for the current scroll position of the window.

When you've scrolled to one of your sections, its `$.offset().top` is 0, even though its not at the top of the page, its at the top of the *screen*.

Adding the current scrollbar position to your `scrollTop` function worked for me:

```
$('a').click(function(){

    var scrollToName = $(this).attr("href").substr(1);
    var scrollTo = $("body").scrollTop() + $('[name="' + scrollToName + '"]').offset().top;

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollTo
    }, 500);
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BFG/31uLm27u/52/)